# Prove that $\binom{n}{r}=\sum^{k}_{l=0}\binom{k}{l}\binom{n-k}{r-l}$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $n$,$k$ and $r$ be positive integers such that $k<r<n$ and also such that $n>r+k.$Prove that $\binom{n}{r}=\sum^{k}_{l=0}\binom{k}{l}\binom{n-k}{r-l}$

I tried to solve using $\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n-1}{r-1}\binom{n-1}{r}$.But could not.I cannot understand how should I proceed?

Thank you.

Comment: The upper bound of your sum can't be $k$ since it's never defined outside the sum .. ? Or do you mean _for any $k$_ ?

Comment: sorry.i edited it.it is $k \lt r \lt n$ and $n \gt r+k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have $n$ man and $m$ women with $k=m+n$.

$\binom{k}{r}$ is the number of group you can form with $r$ person. But you can also form them as taking $\binom{n}{0}$ man and $\binom{m}{r}$ women or $\binom{n}{1}$ man and $\binom{m-1}{r-1}$ women... finally you'll get $$\sum_{i=0}^r\binom{n}{i}\binom{m-r}{r-i}.$$

P.S: there is probably condition on $r$ like $r<n$ or $r<m$ or any other condition, but I let you check all those things to get a valid formula.