# Found a pattern on Pascal's triangle: ${n \choose r}=\sum_{i=0}^k {k \choose i}{n-k \choose r-k+i}$. Has anyone come across it anywhere?

Tags: combinations, binomial-coefficients

In a standard Pascal's triangle, the entry in the $n$th row and $r$th column denoted as ${n \choose r}$ can be expressed using $k+1$ entries $k$ rows above itself as
$${n \choose r}=\sum_{i=0}^k {k \choose i}{n-k \choose r-k+i}$$ where $0\le k\le r$.

A simple example to help visualize the identity:

[image]

[Feel free to play around with values on Desmos calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7qa01t3wur)

Comment: This is one of the most common combinatorial identities.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1524260/215011

Comment: Substitute $k-i$ for $i$, then use the fact that $\binom{k}{k-i}=\binom{k}{i}$ and the Vandermonde identity.